# Nest JS - where to store permissions

Tags: typescript, nestjs, authorization, prisma

I am creating an application in Nest.js and am currently adding authorization. I've been reading about Claims-based authorization and it seems like the perfect solution for my application.
The question is: how should I store permissions and information about which user has which permissions?

The Nest.js documentation describes a case where roles/permissions are in the form of an enum and assigned from the code level, which works with the decorator and guard, but not necessarily anymore if I want to parameterize them (create new ones, assign them from some dashboard, etc.).

The second idea would be to create database relationships, something like `User -many-to-many- UserPermissionPivot -many-to-many- Permissions`. In this case I would have full freedom in parameterization but I have no idea how I could then use them in decorators/guards etc.

Could someone guide me to the right solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have 2 things to solve, in one hand you need to authenticate the user, you could achieve so by storing the credentials a role in a db, which you can use then to know if that user is the one who claims to be and it has the rights to do such operation. On the other side your client can store in memory or a session the roles it contains to use them in conditional formatting for the UI.

It is important that when you authenticate a user operation, you check if that operation is valid against your db and not what is inside the user stored data, otherwise your user could bypass your roles and perform other operations